# Человек получает доступ к PHP коду

Tags: уязвимости, php

Сегодня человек получил как-то список всех файлов моего сайта и доступ к PHP коду.

Как это могло произойти? Он обычный пользователь. Спросив в скайпе у него, мол как так, он ответил:

```
[23:08:12] ManDarin: Посмотри включен или нет get_magic_quotes_gpc
```

Вообщем как защититься?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вообще опция get_magic_quotes_gpc скоро уже должна быть выпилена из языка. Суть в том, что Вы видимо никак не экранируете входящие от пользователя данные. При включенной опции get_magic_quotes_gpc всё должно экранироваться за Вас. То есть такие "вредные" символы как **',\,"** не должны попасть в БД в чистом виде.

Но у Вас, скорее всего, эта опция выключена. Поэтому в запрос к БД достаточно передать символ '(одинарная ковычка) для того, чтобы вызвать ошибку(знающие, не ругайтесь. Я тут слегка утрирую). А затем простая SQL-Injection. 
Узнаем какие таблицы в БД, находим таблицу "user" или типа того, далее находим поле "pass" или типа того. Ну а дальше узнаем логин и хеш пароля(в крайне запущенных случаях там чистый пароль) администратора, расшифровываем и всё. Дальше все просто.

Вам нужно экранировать все входящие из "вне" данные. В php вроде есть mysql_real_escape_string(). Она экранирует все опасные символы. Я думаю Вы ей не пользовались.

Не пытайтесь включить get_magic_quotes_gpc. Её скоро уберут из языка. Так что используйте функции подобные mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: @ModaL Лучше используйте PDO с плейсхолдерами + проверка данных перед запросом для подстраховки (приведение к нужному типу, использование фильтров, к примеру, filter_input_array) - это позволит забыть об SQL-инъекций раз и навсегда.

[Почему стоит пользоваться PDO для работы с базой данных][1]


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/

Кроме того, в PHP 5.5 поддержка старого нативного процедурного доступа к БД не планируется. Смотрите сами:

[http://php.net][2]


  [2]: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: @romeo, спасибо. Мне тоже нужно уходить от старых mysql функций. Все никак не соберусь с силами.

Comment: залить шелл вот так прям через sql inj, кхм, @KryDos что-то скрывает.

Comment: @lampa, не не не. Далее узнаем где админка или пытаемся подсоединится к ftp используя те же имя пользователя и пароль. Или может еще какой-то сервис открыт. Кто знает. Может sql inj там вообще не при чем. Просто предположил. Та и вообще не шарю я в этом :)

Comment: я что-то уверен, что в проекте овер 9000 дыр и надо смотреть каждый файл на возможность "взлома".

Comment: Не, ребят. Данные от MySql и Ftp совершенно разные.. mysql_escape_string уже давно везде стоит.

Comment: @lampa способов залить шелл через инджект тьма.